# Gmail API message duplicates on multiple send API call via REST

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

My target is mail delivery system using Gmail API REST calls from JavaScript, all messages is different and mailing list can reach thousands of people so i cant use CC field. The problem i encounter is message duplicates i get after sending operation is complete. I send 100 messages, and receive over 120 in next 7-20 min.

```
function authorize(credentials) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.web.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.web.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = {redirect_uri};
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, sendMessagePrepair);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      sendMessagePrepair(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
});


var counter = 0;
var before_counter = 0;
var SEND_COUNT = 100;

function sendM(post_req, callback) {
      timeout = before_counter * 100;
      before_counter++;
      setTimeout(function(){
    post_req.write(JSON.stringify({ "raw": mail }));
    post_req.end();
        }, timeout);
}

function sendMessagePrepair(oauth2Client) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
     mail = new Buffer("Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
      "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
      "From: {From}\n" +
      "To: {To}\n" +
      "Subject: {Subject}\n\n" +
       messages
).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

    var post_options = {
  hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
  port: '443',
  path: '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + oauth2Client.credentials.access_token,
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  }
};

    var post_req = [];
    for(var idx = 0; idx < SEND_COUNT; idx++)
      post_req.push(http.request(post_options, function(res) {
         res.setEncoding('utf8');
         res.on('data', function (chunk) {
         console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
         counter++;
         if(counter == SEND_COUNT)
           process.exit();
  });
}));    

  async.map(post_req, sendM, function(e, r){
          console.log(r);
    });
}
```

Sometimes i receive "Limit reached" or "BackendError" RetCode from Google Server, but even with that i still receive more emails then was sent. I got same behavior with Node.JS Google Client Library using:

```
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
gmail.users.messages.send({....},callback);
```

BackendError messages:

> Response: {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "backendError",
>       "message": "Backend Error"    }   ],   "code": 500,   "message": "Backend Error"  } }

My question is: anyone have same problem? Is there any workaround? I cant find anything in net about this behavior.

Comment: Do you have the error message? Have you proib set the interval static mode?

Comment: I got backendError message example, i have edited question and you can see it higher. In my code i use setTimeout with growing timeout value, so there 100ms delay between message send operations.

Comment: Have you checked the actual messages? You might get 20 bounce notification messages from Google in addition to your own messages.

Comment: Yes, there no bounce messages, i have also added identifier to messages, some of them got duplicates, some no.

Comment: @teoring Did you manage to solve this? If not, is it always the same receivers that get the duplicates? Could there be a redirection configured in some accounts, which send the email to another account you're sending to?

Comment: @teoring Yes brother i am getting same email twice. But in backend when i do console.log, i see one for each email . But in the inbox i am getting two emails in different thread